# Why doesn't run my js code in brackets?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
      'use strict';
      function colorClock() {
        'use strict';
        var date = new Date();
        var hour = date.getHours();
        var min = date.getMinutes();
        var sec = date.getSeconds();

        if (hour < 10) {
          hour = '0' + hour;
        }

        if (min < 10) {
          min = '0' + min;
        }

        if (sec < 10) {
          sec = '0' + sec;
        }

        var clockFace = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;

        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = clockFace;
      }
    };
    </script>
```

this is my js code...
it has to show the time in the window.

Why does not it work in brackets, if i link the js file in the ÍheadY section in the .html.

It works fine in JSBin.

Comment: The function is never called

Answer (score 1):

Call your function after creating it:

```
    ...
    }

    colorClock();
};
</script>
```

Note: I'd define the function outside the `window.onload` function, then call it inside the onload block, like this:

```
function colorClock() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var sec = date.getSeconds();

    if (hour < 10) {
      hour = '0' + hour;
    }

    if (min < 10) {
      min = '0' + min;
    }

    if (sec < 10) {
      sec = '0' + sec;
    }

    var clockFace = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;

    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = clockFace;
}

window.onload = function () {
    colorClock()
};
```